# How can I implement a for loop from this MATLAB expression?

Tags: matlab

In the code that follows I am using a step function which uses MATLAB's sign function to create a square pulse train for the variable x. How can this be implemented with a for loop to make things more tidy?

```
del_t=.005
t=-10:del_t:10;         % Time span
L=length(t);
x=stp_fn(t)-stp_fn(t-1)+stp_fn(t-2)-stp_fn(t-3)...     %input x(t) using step function
+stp_fn(t-4)-stp_fn(t-5)+stp_fn(t-6)-stp_fn(t-7)...    %
+stp_fn(t-8)-stp_fn(t-9)+stp_fn(t-10);                 %        

%step function
function u =stp_fn(t)
u=0.5*(sign(t+eps)+1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks a bit unusual, but hey...

```
x = 0;    
for i = 0 : 10
    x = x + (-1)^i*stp_fn(t-i); % ^i for alternating signs...
end
```

Comment: You'd rather do `2 * mod(i, 2) - 1` instead of `(-1) ^ i`. Raising to a power is more expensive than multiplication and subtraction.

Comment: Thanks for this hint! I checked the timing and in fact power seems so be faster than mod for small i (<30) and mod seems to win for i>50.

Answer (score 1):

```
x = stp_fn(t);
for i = 1 : 10
   if mod(i, 2)
      x = x - stp_fn(t - i);
   else
      x = x + stp_fn(t - i);
   end
end
```